# How to reduce the number of columns with multicolumn and *align* them

Tags: tables, longtable, multicolumn, columns

in the following example I want to achieve that the ID A.5.1 is separated with a line from the following text and that this text is also aligned with the second column. So basically I want two first columns for that row, but the second column should be as long as the five columns to the right side of the table.

tldr: continuous  line in the ID column + alignment of the text to the second column

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe=false, left=1.5cm, a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}


\begin{longtable}{V{3}c|c|c|c|c|cV{3}}
\specialrule{0.15em}{0em}{0em}   

ID & \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß \\ ISO/IEC 27001} & \thead[l]{Anwend- \\barkeit} & \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl \\  bzw. Ausschluss} & Maßnahmeziele & Umsetzung \\

\specialrule{0.15em}{0em}{0em}  
\endhead
\multicolumn{6}{V{3}l V{3}}{A.5.1   Vorgaben der Leitung für Informationssicherheit}\\
\hline
A.5.1.1 & \makecell[l]{Informationssicherheits- \\ richtlinien} &  &  & \makecell[l]{Festlegung von \\ Informationssicherheits- \\richtlinien}  & \makecell[l]{Beschreibung in: \\ some.dat}  \\
\hline
A.5.1.2  & Ü & C & D & E & G \\
\end{longtable}


\end{document}
```

Comment: it's not clear what you want but the error is from `\multicolumn{6}{V{3}l V{3}}{A.5.1 &  `  you can not have `&` here, `\multicolumn` makes a single spanning cell you can not have two cells there (where would it align, if it were allowed?)

Comment: Sorry, the & was from my previous attempts to align it. So it is not possible to have two cells there the one which is the ID cell and the other spanning from column 2 to 5?

Comment: I can't guess how you would see the & working how would you know which of the spanned alignment points should be used? If I understand you correctly the A.5.1 is just a normal cell then you want a `\multicolum{5} (not 6) for the following text.

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\multicolumn` can only hold a single cell

If I understand you correctly the A.5.1 is just a normal cell then you want a `\multicolum{5}` (not 6) for the following text.